# fluid container doesnt work with img overlay script

Tags: css, resize, containers, fluid

I am trying to realize a simple website. Menu on top with 3 links, below that a container with 9 images. Imagine rectangular images. I want exactly 3 images per column.

All this is within a bootstrap fluid container for fluid re-sizing with smaller window resolution.

Right now I have different defined containers for each column - I would really like to have them all in one container but somehow the overlay function didnt allow me to do so.

It kind of works right now they way I programmed it but the problem is that when re-sizing the browser window one rather than having always an even amount of images I have 2 images at the top and 1 below that. ( Since I am breaking a column where originally 3 images where inside )

edit : I am repeating project1 / project2 this will later be project 1-9

the fluid containers is from bootstrap

CSS ::::

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css">
.urlImg { width: 300px; height:207px; display:block; background-image: url('buttons/button1a.jpg'); } .urlImg:hover { background-image: url('buttons/button1b.jpg'); }
.urlImg2 { width: 300px; height:207px; display:block; background-image: url('buttons/button2a.jpg'); } .urlImg2:hover { background-image: url('buttons/button2b.jpg'); }
</style>



  <style>  
    div {  
      background: white;  
      color: white;
    }  

    div.padded {  
      padding-top: 30px;  
      padding-right: 10px;  
      padding-bottom: 0.25in;  
      padding-left: 40px; 
    }  
    div.padded2 {  
      padding-top: 30px;  
      padding-right: 10px;  
      padding-bottom: 0.25in;  
      padding-left: 40px; 
      display:inline-block; 
    }  
    div.padded3 {  
      padding-top: 30px;  
      padding-right: 10px;  
      padding-bottom: 0.25in;  
      padding-left: 40px; 
      display:inline-block; 
    }  
    div.padded4 {  
      padding-top: 30px;  
      padding-right: 10px;  
      padding-bottom: 0.25in;  
      padding-left: 40px; 
      display:inline-block; 
    }  
  </style>
```

HTML :::

```
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class=padded><img src="logo.jpg"><img src="spacer.gif" width="34"><a href='projects.htm'><img src="projects.jpg"></a><img src="spacer.gif" width="34"><a href='about.htm'><img src="about.jpg"></a><img src="spacer.gif" width="34"><a href='contact.htm'><img src="contact.jpg"></a></div>

<div class=padded2><a href="project01.htm" class="urlImg" title="project01"></a></div>

<div class=padded2><a href="project02.htm" class="urlImg2" title="project02"></a></div>

<div class=padded2><a href="project01.htm" class="urlImg" title="project01"></a></div>

<br>

<div class=padded3><a href="project02.htm" class="urlImg2" title="project02"></a></div>

<div class=padded3><a href="project02.htm" class="urlImg" title="project01"></a></div>

<div class=padded3><a href="project01.htm" class="urlImg2" title="project02"></a></div>

<br>

<div class=padded4><a href="project02.htm" class="urlImg" title="project01"></a></div>

<div class=padded4><a href="project02.htm" class="urlImg2" title="project02"></a></div>

<div class=padded4><a href="project01.htm" class="urlImg" title="project01"></a></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why are you not just using the Bootstrap structure?

Comment: the thing is just this overlay seems to not work with the div. when I use normal img src it even works in one div. But when I have the overlay it doesnt let me put all the 9 overlays in 1 div.

Comment: I would love to use boostrap is there an overlay available? bootstrap is complteley new to me

Comment: this is the overlay :::     <style type="text/css">
.urlImg { width: 300px; height:207px; display:block; background-image: url('buttons/button1a.jpg'); } .urlImg:hover { background-image: url('buttons/button1b.jpg'); }
.urlImg2 { width: 300px; height:207px; display:block; background-image: url('buttons/button2a.jpg'); } .urlImg2:hover { background-image: url('buttons/button2b.jpg'); }
</style>

Comment: I'm not clear on what it is you are overlaying. Just each image individually? What?

Comment: yes its a simple hover effect. so if your mouse is over that image it changes to another one. so the thing is if I have the fluid-container from boostrap and I just have a div in my html with normal images - it resizes perfectly exactely how it is supposed to be by this i mean now its 9 images ( 3each colum ) it will change to 2 each colum and finally to one image per column. So in general it does work. Just when I have the overlay functions instead of the images in the code it doesnt seem to like it and it will not format it the way it is supposed to look...if I have it in one div it will

Comment: have them under each other. If I have three different divs then it will resize it like I wrote in the first paragraph

Comment: You'll have to make a **minimal** demo as I'm not really grasping the issue. There are literally thousands of questions on SO about overlaying images (Just search "Overlay Image")